# How to Sort by Month's Name

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to sort my data by the month's name but all I can seem to do is sort it in alphabetical order. How would I go about doing this?

Here is the link to my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/sS9dSQ5IknQEsy0L4y1h?p=preview

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.10" data-semver="1.3.10" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy: 'english' | date:'MMMM'">
        <p><strong>{{ month.english | date:"MMMM" }}</strong></p>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any months in your plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should order by `ordinal` instead of `english`. i.e:

`<div ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy: 'ordinal' | date:'MMMM'">`

Comment: It worked! Why couldn't I find that anywhere. Thanks for you help!

Comment: This works because you are sorting by a number, however this would not work if you had a custom date by string. For example: "[January, February, March, April"] would be ordered as April, February, March, and January. So is there a way to do this based on a custom date string and not by an added number to the JSON?

Answer (score 2):

You should change

**From:**

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy: 'english' | date:'MMMM'">
```

**To:**

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy: 'ordinal'  | date:'MMMM'">
```

Working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/sS9dSQ5IknQEsy0L4y1h?p=preview)